# downloaded information keeps cached with .net webclient

Tags: .net, vb.net, caching, webclient

With the code below I'm pretty sure that the downloaded info is cached because I always get the same results in .net.
When I refresh this file in a browser however, then I always get different results.
What can be done?

```
Dim wc As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient
wc.CachePolicy = New System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore)
wc.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")

Dim ds1 As Data.DataSet = New Data.DataSet
Dim ms1 As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(req))
```

Comment: Are you creating a new instance of the the webclient each time you download data?

Comment: Yes, those lines are in a function where the webclient is created each time...

Comment: Try putting a query string on end of url with date and time so the webclient thinks it's different data.  Don't think the httpcient class has this issue

Comment: that is a valid workaround. thx!